# NUnit тесты на C#

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

В общем учусь писать тесты но столкнулся с проблемой что вылазит какая то ошибка

Вот код:

```
namespace testing_lr5
{
    [TestFixture]
    internal class MethodsByTest
    {
        public static int Sum(int a, int b) => a + b;

        [TestCase(0, 0, 0)]
        [TestCase(1, 0, 1)]
        [TestCase(0, 1, 1)]
        [TestCase(1, 1, 2)]

        [Test]
        public static void CalcSumTest(int a, int b, int res)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(Sum(a, b), res);
        }

    }
}
```

скрин ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Главный навык программиста - поиск информации. Вот у вас ошибка, в ней написано `Could not find testhost`, пытаемся найти эту информацию в поисковике, получаем [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLWBR.png), смотрите, сразу куча ответов по вашей проблеме, открываем первые, например, [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469521), ну и сразу видим что большинству помогла установка NuGet пакета `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, а другим помогла смена версии .NET, другие редактируют .csproj файл. И вот смотрите, мы нашли возможные решения за минуту потраченного времени, когда как вы уже 20 мин ждете ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я просто искал в русскоязычных источниках

Comment: Установите [NUnit3TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/)